# Show y values for x axis breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight add y-value text to a plot, but only for those points where I set up x-axis breaks. In my original data, x values are discreate, but to keep things simple lets use a sequence from 0 to 125 as an example and I hope i can transfer the solution for my data on my own. 
If I simply put

```
... + geom_text(aes(label=y),size=3) + ...
```

it'll result in a mess that can't be read. E.g.

[image]

This is what my code for the plot and for my example data looks like.

```
data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%  
  summarise(y= sum(y,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x=x,y=y,group=1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,50,75,100,125))+   
  geom_text(aes(label = y), size = 3)+
  geom_line()


# while the data after summarised looks somethat like this
x <- seq(1,125,1)
y <- x^2
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

Thank you very much for all responses.
Kind regards

> EDIT:
>   In my comments I referred to "strange behavior" and I just wanted to show you what happens on my real data.

[image: strange things happen here]

This does not happen when using the marked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a "second" dataframe for the labels you can add a column with the labels to your dataset. As I learned from Thomas Lin Pedersen's workshop on ggplot2 this approach is more general, e.g. in case you want to use `geom_text_repel` from the `ggrepel` package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1,125,1)
y <- x^2

dat <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%  
  summarise(y= sum(y,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(x %in% c(1,50,75,100,125), y, "")) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x=x,y=y,group=1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,50,75,100,125))+   
  geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 3)+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!
I very much like this solution and how easy and intuitive it can be used. There's also no strange behavior because of the summarise function I use and therefore a well suited solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can include the `subset` argument to the `geom_text` function, which allows you only to plot a subset of the values which satisfy a condition.

```
x <- seq(1,125,1)
y <- x^2

dat <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%  
  summarise(y= sum(y,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x=x,y=y,group=1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,50,75,100,125))+   
  geom_text(data = subset(dat, x %in% c(1,50,75,100,125)), aes(label = y), size = 3)+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution. I feel kind of stupid for missing the use of data and subset to resolve my issue. 
Sadly because of the summarise function, there is a strange behavior using this solution, thus I will use Stefan's solution.